# Turn on/off NEST using REST API

Tags: nest-api

I am looking into options to make rest client to turn on/off nest thermostat from the using web service.

I found API to read the device info, but didn't get API to change settings or turn on and off the device.

Is there any REST/SOAP Api to turn on and off NEST Devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST api for the NEST. The documentation can be seen [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference)

For a thermostat you might not be able to turn it off directly, however setting temperature low enough should emulate off. For example by setting:

```
{ target_temperature_c : 1.0 }
```

Comment: I have tried the URL : https://developer-api.nest.com/devices?auth=c.fDDv3tz8QmAD and payload for PUT is {
 thermostats: {
  -9YM4vnWILB00k6-6ZvKLO3x5G6L0jmH: {
   target_temperature_f: 72,
   target_temperature_high_f: 75,
   target_temperature_low_f: 68
  },
  -9YM4vnWILCBr8k9BP9XRu3x5G6L0jmH: {
   target_temperature_f: 70,
   target_temperature_high_f: 75,
   target_temperature_low_f: 68
  },
  -9YM4vnWILAYKHU3sLJkme3x5G6L0jmH: {
   target_temperature_f: 71,
   target_temperature_high_f: 75,
   target_temperature_low_f: 68
  }
 }
}     The response is 400 {
error: "Invalid content sent"
}

Answer (score 0):

can you format your payload and the response you're getting in the text so its easier to see?

You should PUT to:

`https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/<thermostatID>?auth=<token>`

and your payload should be:

```
{"target_temperature_f":78}
```

Or if you want to turn the system off your payload should be:

```
{"hvac_mode":"off"}
```